# chromedriver in headless mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver for web scraping by giving the binary path.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\bin\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.example.com/")
```

This invoke chromedriver in GUI mode. How can I start chrome in headless mode?

Comment: Have you tried `PhantomJS()`?

Comment: No. How can I use/install it? I using PyCharm Community IDE.

Comment: No, no. It comes with `selenium`. When I made a crawler I faced the same issue, So, I used `webdriver.PhantomJS(URL)`.

Comment: Got it. But I am not familiar with PhantomJS. I know a little bit about chromedriver like find_element_by_id etc. Also, I can easily debug in GUI mode if required and later can go for headless mode. So It will be great if someone can help in that. Maybe later point of time I can try PhantomJS.

Comment: there must be some other options as well. This is what I used, so, I told you.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Let me try @telex-wap method and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome headless is ideally much better than PhantomJS, whose owner decided to stop maintaining the project because the arrival of Chrome headless made it a bit less necessary. That being said, if you have a Chrome version which supports headless, you can do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

As you see, headless is an argument, so if for some reason you want to run the same code but you need to see the GUI, remove that argument.

By the way, if you ever wanted to give the binary location, a nice way to do it is also with options:

```
options.binary_location = 'path to your chrome binary'
```

But if your installed version is recent enough, there should be no reason to do so.

Comment: Yeah, probably better than `PhantomJS`. I guess.

Comment: It's working. chromedriver.exe should be placed where python.exe is present. Thanks